# How do select all elements from table that don't exist in a second table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have two table, A and B where B has a foreign key to A. Rows are inserted into A and after some processing of the data in A a row is inserted into B with a foreign key to A.

How can I select all rows in A that do not have a corresponding row in B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `not exists`  keyword to do the same

```
select key_column from A 
 where not exists (select 1 from B where b.foreign_key_column=a.key_column)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select key_column from A
minus
select foreign_key_column from B;
```

This will give you a list of IDs of values that exist in A but not in B